# What assemblies can I remove when removing Entity Framework from a .net project?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a cs webproject that used to use MS Entity Framwork (v4 or 5 I think) for data access. All data access code is now moved to LLBLGEN.

Which of the following references can I safely remove:

```
System
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Data.Entity
System.Drawing
System.EnterpriseServices
System.Runtime.Serialization
System.Security
System.Transactions
System.Web
System.Web.ApplicationServices
System.Web.DynamicData
System.Web.Entity
System.Web.Extensions
System.Web.Services
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure because we don't know what the rest of your project is using. At a minimum, you should be able to remove `System.Data.Entity`. The `DataSetExtensions` are still in the default list, but primarily apply to LINQ to Datasets which I don't think you'll be using so you should be safe to pull that. It's hard to say if you need the rest or not as we don't know your project.